# SQL UPDATE doesn't update (PYTHON)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm having some trouble with updating already existing values in the table via the user input. When i run the program it prints out a statement saying that the item has been successfully updated, but it doesn't change any of the values.
any help would be great as there doesn't seem to be any errors with my code and I've been stuck on this for a while now.

```
    elif option == "4":
        sqlite3.connect('program.db')
        inp_ID = int(input("Enter the ID of the item you want to update: "))
        itemName = input("Enter New Item Name: ")
        itemPrice = input("Enter the items price: ")
        itemStock = input("Enter the stock amount of the item: ")
        itemDescription = input("Enter a description for the item: ")

        updateSQL = "UPDATE items SET itemName = ?, itemPrice = ?, itemStock = ?, itemDescription = ? WHERE " \
                    "itemID = ? "
        conn.execute(updateSQL, (inp_ID, itemName, itemPrice, itemStock, itemDescription))
        conn.commit()
        print("Item " + itemName + " has been updated.")
```

[HERE IS COMMAND LINE OF WHEN THE PROGRAM IS RUN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CveZd.png)

Comment: You are associating `inp_ID` to the first placeholder (`?`) in the query, which is for `itemName`. Move that to the end of the parameters instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you pass to `execute` aren't in the correct order so no row is matched.

```
conn.execute(
    "UPDATE items SET itemName = ?, itemPrice = ?, itemStock = ?, itemDescription = ? WHERE itemID = ? ",
    (
        itemName,
        itemPrice,
        itemStock,
        itemDescription,
        inp_ID,
    ),
)
```

is likely what you're looking for.

You can also use named placeholders to make things easier to manage.

```
conn.execute(
    "UPDATE items SET itemName = :name, itemPrice = :price, itemStock = :stock, itemDescription = :desc WHERE itemID = :id",
    {
        "name": itemName,
        "price": itemPrice,
        "stock": itemStock,
        "desc": itemDescription,
        "id": inp_ID,
    },
)
```